# How to put h1 and text in headers on the same line without inline HTML

Tags: html, css

I just have started with HTML and just basically trying around. So I have found some (Quite alot) stackoverflow where people are wondering the same and I just found out that alot of people using inline and my thought was if there is a way to maybe do it without a inline and I haven't come to any answers and here iam!

I have tried to do so far:

```css
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Left Text</h1>
    <span class="right">Right Text</span>
</header>
```

and it ends up pretty bad I would say

[Picture of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiaBI.png)

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`<h1>` tag in HTML is `display: BLOCK` element by default, So it comes with a new line always. If you want `<span>` tag to be displayed on the same line just change the `<h1>` tag display to inline.

```
<h1 style="display: inline;"> Left Text </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<h1>Left Text 
  <span style="float:right">Right Text</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.Right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 class="left">Left Text </h1>
    <span class="Right">Right Text</span>
</header>
```